# Unable to refresh data for a data connection in the workbook.

Tags: excel, excel-services

I am trying to use an Excel Web Part that connects to a list in Sharepoint 2010.

On my local drive the spreadsheet updates when I open it and all is well but when I uploaded to sharepoint the data will not refresh  Instead I get

Unable to refresh data for a data connection in the workbook. 
Try again or contact your system administrator. 
The following connections failed to refresh: 
list42901

I believe it is becuase the file connection iqy file is on mylocal?

How do I change that?

Comment: I followed the steps in this site  sharepointboost /blog/ use-the-sharepoint-2010-excel-service-to-create-a-bi-tool

Comment: Which version of excel are you dealing with

Comment: I am using MS Excel 2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a Data Source document library in your Sharepoint site and upload the iqy file there. Check it in and approve it. Rebuild your workbook to use that datasource. Publish via Excel Services.

Comment: I did the above but I still get Unable to refresh data for a data connection in the workbook. 
Try again or contact your system administrator. The following connections failed to refresh: 

list42901

Comment: I'm having the same issue... still not able to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the content in Excel workbook (Source workbook) and pasted the copied data using Paste Link in destination workbook.
Then you can get the data you want.